# How to override CTRL+Y in a python script?

Tags: python, signals, hotkeys

I want to implement <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> as a hotkey in my python script, however, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> will cause a signal to be sent to my script, causing it to stop.

How can I override the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> key combination within the python script?

I have tried:

```
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGSTOP, signal.SIG_IGN)
```

but this will cause `RunTimeError (22, 'invalid argument')`.

Comment: Whether or not CTRL+Y sends a signal to your script is terminal-dependent (and configurable *from* the terminal).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to interrupt `SIGSTOP` [which is uninterruptible](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=signal&sektion=3&manpath=freebsd-release-ports). You want to interrupt `SIGTSTP` like so:

```
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGTSTP, signal.SIG_IGN)
```

Comment: That prevents ^Y from stopping the program, but the key still doesn't get transmitted, it's just ignored now.